# How can I properly convert image to gray scale in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, grayscale

I want to find contours on the image below (white bubbles). The problem is that when I convert the image to gray with the standard way:

```
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

I do not see them (second image). Is it possible to change the conversion some how? Thank you for any help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show the complete code which you are using. Maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: yes, I have found the problem in another line. Thank you!!!

Comment: Then please add your solution as an answer so that other users can also know the cause of problem and its solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("WNrrP.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("h",img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

This works correctly for me

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine for me. Please insure that visualisation code is correct.
Here is a screenshot of the my code which I ran to test your images.
[Screenshot of code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKCMj.png)

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Copy paste it to you question/answer

Comment: I am new here. Will surely keep this in mind. Thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the different line before. The cvtColor works fine